# JSON to php accessing

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array created using Javascript.

I stringify it before putting it into an input field and submit it with a HTML form.

This is my output after decoding:

var_dump(json_decode($_POST['json']),true); outputs:

```
[{"Mid": "1", "cat": "6", "room": "21", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,2,1"}, {"Mid": "2", "cat": "3", "room": "12", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,1,1"}]
```

Then every time I try to access any property I get an error. I tried:

```
$jsonObj->Mid //gives "Trying to get property of non-object in..."

$jsonObj[0]->Mis //error again.
```

Basically I need to extract each object in a `for` loop. Please help me figure out how to access or get  all the object properties in loops.

Thanks

Comment: The second attempt was alright, apart from the typo. See also http://array.include-once.org/ for JSON/array traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the json string into a php object

`$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonObj)`

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` will give you an array of two objects from this json input:

```
$json = '[{"Mid": "1", "cat": "6", "room": "21", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,2,1"}, {"Mid": "2", "cat": "3", "room": "12", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,1,1"}]';
$result = json_decode($json);
var_dump($result);
```

---

Access them using the array access operator `[]`:

```
echo $result[0]->Mid;
```

or

```
echo $jsonObj[1]->Mid;
```

Comment: I tried the way you told me but this is what i get after $jsonObj[0]->Mid; ===>  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: I got `string(1) "1"` or `string(1) "2"`.. Are you sure you executed the example as simple as I've posted it?

Comment: This is the output of var_dump: string(152) "[{"Mid": "1", "cat": "6", "room": "21", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,2,1"}, {"Mid": "2", "cat": "3", "room": "12", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,1,1"}]"

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($result[0]->Mid);` ?

Comment: And you are sure that you've executed *just* my example?

Comment: I have created var jsonObj=new Array(); then added objects using jsonObj.push({Mid: id,cat:tid,room:rid,rate:rateid,adchexb:persons}); and then I stringify before submitting the form

Comment: ? What has this to do with the question??

Comment: giving you a little details about the flow

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to utilize an additional argument with the `json_encode` function you can add a second argument. For example:

```
$myArray = json_decode($jsonObj,true);
```

Now the `$myArray` will be an associate array that you access like this:

```
$myArray[0]['Mid'];
```

Comment: I tried that this is the error I am getting :Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in...

Comment: `var_dump()` the `myArray` variable and see what it looks like

Comment: string(152) "[{"Mid": "1", "cat": "6", "room": "21", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,2,1"}, {"Mid": "2", "cat": "3", "room": "12", "rate": "EURP", "adchexb": "2,1,1"}]"

Comment: try accessing via `$myArray['mid']`